# Python 3 if not condition simplification

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Are these two condition checks the same? I can't think of how to check if they are the same

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

if not l1 and not l2:
    print ('y')

if not (l1 and l2):
    print ('y')
```

thanks to all who replied, I have done some basic timing to see which is faster

```
import time
l1 = []
l2 = []

st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    if not l1 and not l2:
        pass
end = time.time()
print ('if not l1 and not l2: '+str(end-st))

st = time.time()
for i in range(100000000):
    if not (l1 or l2):
        pass
end = time.time()
print ('if not (l1 or l2): '+str(end-st))
```

prints:

```
if not l1 and not l2: 8.533874750137329
if not (l1 or l2): 7.91820216178894
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. You need to modify the second condition as follows, so that they would be equivalent:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

if not l1 and not l2:
    print ('y')

if not (l1 or l2):
    print ('y')
```

Answer (score 7):

No, they are not the same.  See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

A counter-example is:

```
l1 = [0]
l2 = []
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be the same, use or operation:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

if not l1 and not l2:
    print ('y')
```

equivalent:

```
if not (l1 or l2):
    print ('y')
```